# split a html line to multiple lines

Tags: html, split

I need some help.
I have some files which are like

```
<table><tr><td>This is a  test</td></tr><td><div align="center"><img src=""><a href="">test</a></td></table>
```

I am trying to split them like

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>This is a  test</td>
</tr>
<td>
<div align="center">
<img src="">
<a href="">test</a>
</td>
</table>
```

Can you help?

Thank you

Comment: which editor you are using?

Comment: https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Comment: I was able to do it with sed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using sed and more specific like this

```
sed -i 's/></>\n</g' file1
```